# Is there a way to choose the lower priced shipping method of two carriers under a generic name?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

So I will try to explain this as good as possible. We will ship with FedEx and UPS, and some items also with USPS. As we all know FedEx has the Express Saver which is comparable to UPS 3 Day Select. FedEx Ground is comparable to UPS Ground and so forth. What I would like to do is the following:

Display for shipping option something like this:

Ground $x.xx
3 Day  $x.xx
2 Day  $x.xx
1 Day  $x.xx

Not stating if it is UPS or FedEx, but simply use the lower priced service. So if FedEx Ground is cheaper than UPS ground then just show the FedEx Ground price as "Ground". If UPS 3 day is cheaper than fedex express saver then just show UPS 3 Day price as "3 Day $x.xx", etc. etc.

Do you know of such an extension?

Another question would be the display of the different shipping methods. For example UPS shows the word UPS in front of all of their methods in Magento, like: UPS Ground, UPS 3 Day Select, UPS 2nd Day Air, ....

However FedEx and USPS for example only show: Ground, Express Saver, Priority Mail, etc. etc.

Question: is there a way to show the all FedEx and USPS shipping option names with either FedEx or USPS in front of it?

Again, if anyone has any idea please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

No idea how to show only the lowest price, but adding carrier in front of the methods, here's something to try.

In this folder, you can edit the files for your carrier. However, it's a core file and will be overwritten when updated, so this isn't a 'preferred' method.

Go to

app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/FedEx.php

Look for

```
'FEDEX_2_DAY'                         => Mage::helper('usa')->__('2 Day'),
```

and then change it to something like

```
'FEDEX_2_DAY'                         => Mage::helper('usa')->__('FedEx 2 Day'),
```

That will allow the carrier name in front of the method. YOu can edit any method you want there. For instance, you can change "Economy Express" to "FedEx 3 Day" as most people don't know what Economy Express is.

Bad news, I've never found a method to add the "USPS" in front of USPS methods, without wrecking the function.

Hope that helps some

Comment: Thank you, but doing a core hack in my eyes is generally bad practice. Looking for a less invasive solution. Also USPS can't be solved this way either so it seems... I will keep on looking, but thanks for taking your time to reply!

Comment: Please let me know if you find a solution to the USPS, it's always bugged me and wish it would show the carrier + method as well.